# How far has the Markovian invasion progressed?

Tags: dc, black-lightning-2018

In Season 3 of *Black Lightning*, at the beginning of the season, we see that Freeland is under military control, with some sort of force field around the perimeter. This is described as an "invasion" and a "war," and it seems like we are not dealing with metaphor here. Markovian soldiers roam freely around the outskirts of the city, while the city itself is militarized.

What is unclear is how far the invasion has progressed. On the one hand, it seems strange that a foreign army could have roving special forces squads around a major US city for any significant time, with the US military also being aware of this, without controlling a great deal of surrounding territory. On the other hand, the number of Markovian soldiers seems kind of low for assaulting their highest-priority target, if they have enough forces to control most of the space around it. Further, apparently some farms can still sell to the city, and the ASA sees the need to block outside media presence (presumably Markovia would take care of that if they controlled the outside).

So, how much of the country has Markovia been able to conquer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not very far.**

The evidence suggests that the invasion at the beginning of the third season is extremely limited in scale, and that military control of the US may not even be the goal.

As previously mentioned, the Perdi farm is not under the control of the Markovian forces, in spite of the fact that there were roving Markovian forces around the farm. Similarly, the city continues to be (fairly) adequately supplied with food and other supplies: it may be intercepted and sold for ridiculous prices, or doled out by the ASA, but it's not completely lacking the way one might expect if the Markovian army had the city completely besieged.

The strongest evidence is that newcasters in cities as close as Jacksonville were reporting on the situation in Freeland. If Markovia had had control of their cities, they would presumably not have been able to continue reporting on the situation, let alone from a point of view favorable to the US government. Similarly, the fact that the protagonists were trying to get a message out to show the country what was really going on in Freeland suggests that Markovia was not in control—presumably they would be uninterested in reports of US government atrocities.

For that matter, the fact that the ASA is pushing a propaganda narrative, saying that Freeland is experiencing an outbreak of a new, mutated form of SARS (prescient....), is a strong indication that the invasion is confined to the immediate vicinity of Freeland. Not only would they been unable to conceal the existence of the invasion if Markovia were occupying a larger area, I cannot see why they would *want* to.

One of the Markovian soldiers suggests that their main objective is *not* to take control of the entire country, but rather to acquire the metahuman stabilization formula that Dr. Stewart developed. They would then use that to stabilize their own frozen metahumans, to be used in a more conventional war in the future. Presumably they lack the means, at that point in time and without their own stable metahumans, to simply openly fight the entire US military.

So, how can this be reconciled with the small numbers of Markovian soldiers, and persistence of their invasion in the face of the overwhelming numerical superiority of the ASA, not to mention the ASA's technological resources, like the ability to create a giant force field around the city?

It is not too hard to imagine how Markovia could muster a few hundred special forces soldiers around Freeland. They probably have spies around the nation who could come to Freeland, and they have literally contracted the services of a teleporter, potentially enabling them to bring soldiers from Markovia directly to the US. In fact, evidence suggests that many of the soldiers are being deployed in exactly this manner, directly from Markovia.

As for why the ASA cannot simply flood the surrounding area with tens of thousands of US soldiers, and flush the Markovian forces out of their hiding places instead of playing defense, it seems that as though the top priority of the ASA is to win the *propaganda* war. The ASA is defending a fixed objective against a highly mobile enemy: besides being able to move hundreds of soldiers around in minutes with teleportation, the Markovian forces may also have technological or metahuman means of concealment. To find and defeat all the Markovian forces, they would have to deploy a huge number of soldiers in a large radius around Freeland. But  as soon as they did that, they would have lost. They could not keep the fact of the Markovian invasion secret, which which would be a huge morale blow: enemy forces from a small European country can infiltrate America at any time with the help of metahumans, and the government can't prevent it. More importantly, then they would blow up the  whole lie about a viral outbreak in Freeland, and when people came inquiring, that would probably expose the truth of their detainment of suspected metahumans, which would be quite the scandal. Finally, as long as Markovia has access to teleporters and such, they would be able to redeploy their covert operations forces the minute the ASA withdrew.

In fact, evidence at the end of the show suggests that the ASA was operating without the express authorization of much of the government, although the president certainly was aware of their operations. Presumably to bring in any significant number of troops to Freeland would require making Congress and such aware, which in turn would expose their operations. As we see at the end, the ASA would rather lose all of Freeland than have information about their work get out.

Because of all this, the ASA cannot risk exposing itself by launching the massive assault that would be necessary to eliminate the Markovian forces around Freeland, and thus those forces can stay in place despite the fact that the ASA could theoretically take control of their territory.

Finally, we cannot ignore the possibility that Odell purposely holds back on the possibility of eliminating the Markovian forces. The threat from Markovia is obviously real, but all the evidence suggests Odell is very glad to have the opportunity to use this threat to control Freeland. The experiments that Proctor had to do in secret in the first season, Odell can do openly while Markovia remains a danger. Eliminating Markovian forces from the area around Freeland would not substantially affect the ability of Markovia to launch rapid assaults against ASA bases, but it would certainly reduce Odell's ability to justify his occupation.